# Added new block of elements dynamicily

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have solved this situation many time,but haven't found good way yet.
In mvc page I have:

```
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        <label>Label @i </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubSiteNames[i - 1])
        <br />
    }
    <input type="button" value="+"  />
```

Then on page I want to click '+' button and add another pair of label and button.

What is the best way to do it?

Note:

There isn't problem with binding.

Comment: my co worker uses knockout js http://knockoutjs.com/ for stuff like this

Answer (score 1):

Here goes my answer with PartialViews. There are many other ways to solve this problem, like using plainly client-side jquery (with out hitting server action). I would recommend you to explore those solutions too.

Models -

```
public class Site
{
    public List<SubSite> SubSiteNames { get; set; }
}
public class SubSite
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller -

```
public class TableController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Site sn = new Site();
        sn.SubSiteNames = new List<SubSite>();
        sn.SubSiteNames.Add(new SubSite() { Name = "a.microsoft.com" });
        sn.SubSiteNames.Add(new SubSite() { Name = "b.microsoft.com" });
        return View(sn);
    }

    public ActionResult SubSite()
    {
        return PartialView("_SubSite");
    }
}
```

Index View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.Site

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SubSite")",
                type: "GET",
                error: function (response) {
                    if (!response.Success)
                        alert("Error");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#content").append(response);
                }
            });

        });
    })
</script>
<div id="content">
    @foreach (var item in Model.SubSiteNames)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_SubSite", item);
    }
</div>

<input type="button" value="+" id="ClickMe" />
```

_SubSite Partial View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.SubSite

<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

Output, When we click on + Sign -

[image]

Answer (score -1):

JQuery is perfect for this sort of thing.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/